# Laravel nova - press delete button no confirmation modal appears

Tags: laravel, modal-dialog

I am using the Nova administration panel, and everything works correctly, except when I go to delete a resource record.

When I press the delete button, I don't get the confirmation modal if I want to delete it and the whole screen is grayed out.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nn6qw.jpg)

I have tried to clean up using the commands:

- php artisan nova:publish --force
- php artisan nova:publish
- php artisan optimize:clear

But none of that worked.

Has anyone had the same thing happen or know where the problem may be coming from.

Help is very appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the console for any indication of missing files? That looks like it could be a missing CSS file, for example.

Comment: Yes, I have checked it but it does not show any error. 
Regarding your question, I have run "npm run dev" inside the nova public root "\vendor\laravel\nova\public" and then run again the "php artisan nova:publish"  but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem. The error was being caused by the **emotality/summernote-nova** package. I tried to do a clean install of Nova, and install the packages from my old project one by one in the new one. Everything was working, until I installed this one, then the same error started repeating. I uninstalled it and everything worked again.